# Make insert or update to SQLite taking care of empty table

Tags: android, android-sqlite

The logic has to decide whether it will `insert` or `update` the table and yet it has to check if the table is not empty since.

So the current version of the code looks like this

```
if ((new XYZController(mContext)).getCount() == 0) {
    new XYZController(mContext).insert(object);
} else {
    XYZObject obj = (new XYZController(mContext)).getByString(string);
    if (obj == null) {
        new XYZController(mContext).insert(object);
    } else {
        new XYZController(mContext).update(object);
    }
}
```

Since I cannot do `WHERE` query on empty SQLite table, I have to make additional "if empty" check.

Is there a way to omit such flow and just do 1 insert and 1 update caring if the table is empty or not?

PS. If we try to make a `WHERE` query on empty table, the app will break on the `cursor.getString()`

```
public XYZModel getByString(String s) {
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_XYZ
            + " WHERE " + COLUMN + "='" + s + "'";
    Cursor cursor = getRow(selectQuery);

    XYZModel walk = null;
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        obj = new XYZModel(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),
                cursor.getString(3));
    }
    if (obj == null)
        obj = new XYZModel();

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: You could simply use a `REPLACE INTO`. If the record exists, it will be replaced, if it doesn't it will be inserted. You'll need to run it through `execSQL()`

Comment: `REPLACE INTO` is also known as `INSERT OR REPLACE`. There is also `INSERT OR IGNORE`, if you want to leave an existing row alone if it exists by its primary key. "Since I cannot do WHERE query on empty SQLite table, I have to make additional "if empty" check" -- huh? `WHERE` will return zero rows for an empty table, just as it will return zero rows for a non-empty table but one that does not match the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: "If we try to make a WHERE query on empty table, the app will break on the cursor.getString()" -- that is because you fail to see if your `Cursor` has any rows.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks. I fixed a Cursor checking for 0 rows. My question is shall I completely drop usage of `UPDATE` in SQLite and switch to `INSERT OR REPLACE`?

Comment: "My question is shall I completely drop usage of UPDATE in SQLite and switch to INSERT OR REPLACE?" -- I cannot answer that, as I do not know your business rules. `insertWithOnConflict()` is basically a flavor of `insert()` that allows the same sort of conflict resolution, so you can use the accepted answer, if that's what you mean. But what the right conflict resolution policy is (ignore, replace, etc.) is up to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure your table has reasonable uniqueness constraints, such as a `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE` constraint on some columns
2. Just use an insert with a conflict resolution algorithm such as replace, for example:

   ```
   db.insertWithOnConflict(tableName, null, contentValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
   ```

If the insert would violate a constraint, the conflicting rows are first *deleted* and then the new row is inserted. Therefore make sure you're providing a value for each column.

In case you have a database-generated `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, you can initially supply a `NULL` for its value (`ContentValues.putNull()`) and then capture the return value of the insert to get the generated primary key value.

This way you don't need the (incorrect) code that checks whether the row exists, nor do you need separate branches for inserts and updates.